# Front Mountain Bike Cable Disk Brake Is Too Snappy on First Pull

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

When I grab my front disk brake for the first time on a ride after my bike has sat for a while it will buck me forward.  Once it bucks me it works great.  I have tried cleaning it with disc brake cleaner but I have not seen any improvement.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could the cable or lever be stiff at first then free up after the first use? What happens if you give it a good hard squeeze or two before you get going?

Comment: Is there rust in the cable or on the rotor?  Do the pads look okay?

Comment: It could be that the cable needs lubrication, but it really sounds like oxide forming on the rotor, and you probably just need to live with it.

Answer (score -1):

I  removed my brake pads and sprayed the pads and disk with some good cleaner and so far it has been a success.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @kavikkid. This site is different to a regular chat forum; it works on a question and answer basis. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to understand how it works.

Comment: @Kavikkid, are you the same person that posted the question, and are you saying that the comments on the question helped you fix your problem, or are you different person?